# having problems to remove the loader from the stage

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I am new to Action script but almost made a simple game so far. My problem is that when I call my `testForEnd()` function, loader images don't disappear from that screen and because of that I can't see my GAME END screen. I did some research on `removeChild()`, hoping that that would solve my problem, but that didn't work. Any help would be appreciated!

```
function testForEnd():void
{

    if ( score > level*30)
    {
        level++;
        level_txt.text = String(level);

        req = new URLRequest("images/" +imageNumber + ".jpg");
        loader = new Loader();
        imageNumber++;
        loader.load(req);
        addChildAt(loader,getChildIndex(settingMenu));

        if( imageNumber >= 20 ) {
            imageNumber = 0;
        }


        var tempLevelUp:LevelUp  = new LevelUp();
        addChild(tempLevelUp);
        tempLevelUp.x = stage.stageWidth / 2 - tempLevelUp.width / 2
        tempLevelUp.y = stage.stageHeight / 2 - tempLevelUp.height / 2
        if (tempLevelUp.currentFrame >= tempLevelUp.totalFrames)
        {

            removeChild(tempLevelUp);
        }


    }
    if (lives == 0) {


        gameState = STATE_END_GAME;




        }

    //gameState = STATE_END_GAME;
    trace(gameState);
}


function endGame():void
{
    removeGame();
    endScreen.visible = true;

    // this is where it doesn't work loader visible
    loader.visible = false;

   // also i tried removeChild which didn't work
   removeChild(loader);

    removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, gameLoop);
    showResults();
}



function removeGame():void
{
    // gameState = STATE_END_GAME;
    for (var i:int = enemies.length-1; i>=0; i--) 
{

    removeEnemy(i);

}

    for (var j:int = Lasers.length - 1; j >=0; j--) 
{
    removeLaser(j);

}

    for (var k:int = explosions.length - 1; k >=0; k--) 
{
    removeExplosion(k);

}



removeChild(player);
laserTimer.stop();

}
```

Comment: When you call endGame at what context is it called? When you just try to `removeChild(loader)` it could be possible, that the `loader` is added to another movieclip. Check at what object you are adding the loader when calling `addChildAt(loader,getChildIndex(settingMenu));`, keep somewhere a reference to it and then, try to remove it in `endGame` with `object.removeChild(loader);`

Comment: @23tux var req:URLRequest; 
var loader:Loader; 
are the global variables, those are being called to main timeline , i haven't kept them in any movieClip. maybe if i keep them in a movieClip and give a reference to remove it that might could solve this problem? how can i keep my image loader request in a movieClip

Answer (score 1):

You seem to have made a typo on the visible property

```
loader.visble = false;
```

Should be visible instead of visble.

As long as you have it as visble, it will throw a ReferenceError.

Comment: sorry its already loader.visible = true but still couldn't fix that problem

Comment: @23tux, thanks i fixed this problem , i guess i haven't given any reference of movieClip to load the images, so it was independent to timeline and had no control over it, so i kept that in a movieclip and simply removed that movieClip reference and it worked , thank you guys